# Java Power function answers

Tags: java, int

I was writing my own implementation of the power function and I discovered some weird results that occur at around `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which I'm not sure why they occur.
This is my implementation:

```
public static long power(long x, long y) {
    int result = 1;
    while (y > 0) {
        if ((y & 1) == 0) {
            x *= x;
            y >>>= 1;
        } else {
            result *= x;
            y--;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The the following code is run,

```
System.out.println(fastPower(2, 31));
System.out.println(Math.pow(2, 31);
System.out.println((long)Math.pow(2, 31));
System.out.println((int)Math.pow(2, 31));
```

The results as follows, which I do not understand.

```
-2147483648
2.147483648E9
2147483648
2147483647
```

This further confuses me when `short`s are used:

```
System.out.println(fastPower(2, 15));
System.out.println(Math.pow(2, 15));
System.out.println((int)Math.pow(2, 15));
System.out.println((short)Math.pow(2,15));

32768
32768.0
32768
-32768
```

These are the answers that I would expect, but they seem inconsistent with the results from `int`s.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think OP understands that an overflow is happening. What they does not understand is why the last `short` is behaving differently.

Comment: @Carcigenicate "Shouldn't `System.out.println((int)Math.pow(2, 31));` print `-2147483648` as well?" is possibly what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think I found the answer in the language spec. It's about how doubles are converted to integer types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three outputs from both `int` and `short` are easy to explain:

```
-2147483648 // your method returns an int, so overflows
2.147483648E9 // Math.pow returns a double, so formatted like this
2147483648 // double casted to a long, 2147483648 inside the possible range for long

32768 // your method returns an int, 32768 is inside the possible range for int
32768.0 // Math.pow returns a double, so formatted like this
32768 // double casted to an int, 32768 is inside the possible range for int
```

The hard to explain bit is the fourth result. Shouldn't `System.out.println((int)Math.pow(2, 31));` print -2147483648 as well?

The trick here is how Java does a conversion from `double` to `int`. According to the spec, this is known as a narrowing primitive conversion ([§5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)):

> 22 specific conversions on primitive types are called the narrowing
>   primitive conversions:
>
> - short to byte or char
> - char to byte or short
> - int to byte, short, or char
> - long to byte, short, char, or int
> - float to byte, short, char, int, or long
> - double to byte, short, char, int, long, or float

This is how a `double` to `int` conversion is carried out (bolded by me):

> **1. In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a long, if T is long, or to an int, if T is byte, short, char, or int,
>   as follows:**
>
> - If the floating-point number is NaN(§4.2.3), the result of the first step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
> - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, rounding toward
>     zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3). Then there are
>     two cases:
>
> a. If T is long, and this integer value can be represented as a long,
>   then the result of the first step is the long value V. b. Otherwise,
>   if this integer value can be represented as an int, then the result of
>   the first step is the int value V.
>
> - **Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true:** a. The value must be too small (a negative value of large magnitude or negative
>     infinity), and the result of the first step is the smallest
>     representable value of type int or long. **b. The value must be too
>     large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and
>     the result of the first step is the largest representable value of
>     type int or long.**
>
>   2. In the second step:
> - **If T is int or long, the result of the conversion is the result of the first step.**
> - **If T is byte, char, or short, the result of the conversion is the result of a narrowing conversion to type T (§5.1.3) of the result of
>     the first step.**

The first step changes the double to the largest representable value of `int` - 2147483647. This is why in the `int` case, 2147483647 is printed. In the `short` case, the second step changes the `int` value of 2147483647 to a `short`, like this:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T.

This is why the `short` overflew, but the `int` did not!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `power()` and `fastPower()` are the same, `fastPower(2, 31)` returns `-2147483648` because `result` variable is `int`, even though parameters and return type are all `long`.

`Math.pow()` returns a `double`, so casting of result to integral type (`long`, `int`, `short`, `byte`, `char`) follows the rules of [JLS 5.1.3. Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), quoted below.

`Math.pow(2, 31)` is `2147483648.0`. When cast to `long`, it's the same value, i.e. `2147483648`. When cast to `int` however, the value is too large so result is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, i.e. `2147483647`, as highlighted in the quote below.

`Math.pow(2, 15)` is `32768.0`. When cast to `int`, it's the same value, i.e. `32768`. When cast to `short` however, the value is *first* narrowed to `int`, *then* narrowed to `short` by discarding higher bits (see second quote below), resulting in numeric overflow to `-32768`.

> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type T takes two steps:
>
> 1. In the first step, the **floating-point number is converted** either to a `long`, if T is `long`, or **to an `int`**, if T is `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`, as follows:
>
>    - If the floating-point number is NaN ([§4.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)), the result of the first step of the conversion is an `int` or `long` `0`.
>    - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value `V`, rounding toward zero using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode ([§4.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3)). Then there are two cases:
>
>      1. If T is `long`, and this integer value can be represented as a `long`, then the result of the first step is the `long` value `V`.
>      2. Otherwise, if this integer value can be represented as an `int`, then the result of the first step is the `int` value `V`.
>    - Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true:
>
>      1. The value must be too small (a negative value of large magnitude or negative infinity), and the result of the first step is the smallest representable value of type `int` or `long`.
>      2. **The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type `int` or `long`.**
> 2. In the second step:
>
>    - If T is `int` or `long`, the result of the conversion is the result of the first step.
>    - If T is `byte`, `char`, or `short`, the result of the conversion is the result of a narrowing conversion to type T ([§5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)) of the result of the first step.

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the *n* lowest order bits, where *n* is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

Comment: Wow, we answered at nearly the same time!